# Android Studio SDK manager takes up more than 10GB on mac .. is this normal?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, sdk

I downloaded Android Studio on Mac, and from Android SDK Manager I installed

- Android 5.1.1(API22)
- Extras

I had 11GB of free disk space, but it all ran out and couldn't install all of them. Is it normal for SDKs to take up this much of disk space?

Are there any unnecessary items that I can skip installing?

Comment: open terminal, type: "cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/ & du -sh *" see what is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's normal on, y computer SDK only took about 20GB.

the another part of your question: yes there is a lot of unimportant things: I will mention only what you need to start:

**Android 5.1.1(API22):** The documentation for android SDK, SDK Platform Intel x86Atom System image.

**Tools**: First three items.

this is all you need to get starting.